# What is the process for selling a domain to a stranger?

Tags: domains, domain-transfer

I have what I believe is a legitimate offer for a domain I own, and am considering accepting it, but I'm not sure how to proceed in a way that ensures that both parties get what they agree to (control of the domain for the purchaser, and the offered cash for me).

What is the process for selling a domain to a stranger?

Comment: Please specify more your question and domain extension, as any possible answer would be too broad or unspecific to you.

Comment: @Mike I disagree and OP has accepted the answer.  The process to ensure that both parties get what they agree to, which is the crux of the question, applies to any domain extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use an escrow service.  Consider them a disinterested 3rd party who will hold the money and hold the domain registration.  When both parties agree that the sale has been successful, they will hand over the proceeds to you and the domain login to them.

They generally charge a fee for this service.